# How to check if ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class middleware is registered in Laravel 11

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware, laravel-11

Through Laravel 10, I was able to check if the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware was globally registered by using the following code:

```php
$kernel = $this->getLaravel()->make('App\\Http\\Kernel');

$exists = $kernel->hasMiddleware(\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class);
```

However, the `Kernel` class was removed in Laravel 11. How can I check if the `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware is registered now?

Answer (score 0):

The `App\Http\Kernel` class was removed from the Laravel 11 skeleton application, but the `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel` class is still used by the framework. Additionally, as seen in the `index.php`, you can resolve the used instance from the `Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel` interface.

You should be able to update your code to:

```
$kernel = $this->getLaravel()->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$exists = $kernel->hasMiddleware(\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class);
```